# Bootstrap make column stay at the bottom of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay guys so I have this green container: 
[image]

**And I need the text** - Would you like to chat ? - **to be at the bottom of it's parent** (the green background) 
[image]

I tried adding a style to the text like this:

```
<div class="row" style="position: relative;">
     <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0; right:0;"> Would you like to chat ? </div>   
</div>
```

But that did not work, the text is just over another text, not bottom.
**I do not want to use margin-top, because it won't be good at mobile screens.**

Here is the code:

```
    <!-- About page -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 

            <div class="col-lg-6 bg-success">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="images/girlprofile.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="pic1notworking" height="220" width="220" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 15px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"  style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 15px;">
                    <center> 
                        <div class="usernamestyle"> Username <br> </div> 
                        <div class="onlinestyle">
                         is currently online <br> 
                         Would you like to chat ? <br>

                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p style="font-size: 140%"> 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In condimentum, felis ac tristique tempor, tortor justo fringilla erat, id porta dui nisl quis leo. Proin non quam vitae erat placerat tincidunt. Mauris aliquam tempor finibus. Nulla a purus vehicula, tempus augue placerat, tincidunt odio. Mauris aliquet placerat urna vitae fermentum. Duis posuere risus ac elit mattis gravida. Pellentesque a quam eu massa efficitur aliquam. <br> <br>
                Suspendisse tincidunt convallis nulla in pharetra. Ut ac erat convallis, dictum velit nec, sagittis ipsum. Quisque venenatis, nisi id consectetur imperdiet, nibh velit scelerisque arcu, ac placerat neque elit sit amet nisl. Aliquam nec dolor quam. Pellentesque maximus dui id justo ullamcorper auctor. Ut placerat purus vitae ipsum sodales, vel molestie magna finibus.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.usernamestyle{
  font-size: 200%;

}

.onlinestyle{
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

Comment: Please add your css as well

Comment: @RasmusGlevig Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="position: relative;height:100%; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 15px;">
  <center> 
    <div class="usernamestyle"> Username <br> </div> 
    <div class="onlinestyle">
    is currently online
    </div>
  </center>
  <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0; right: 0;">
    Would you like to chat ?
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The text just overlaps over the "is currently online"

Comment: @IkePr Try this please.

Comment: @IkePr Add height at .col-lg-6

Comment: Yes that works ! Great job, thanks. I thought there was a more simpler method.